# How to consult a file in prolog from mongodb or java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, prolog

I'm implementing a web application with Java which in a part of it, I create a SWI-Prolog file. I know about the `consult` command in Prolog but this command needs an **absolute path**. But, because i use MongoDB to store my results i would like to store that file in Mongo and not to create directory on my project filesystem to `consult` the file. Is it possible to `consult` the file to Prolog without having the actual ***.pl** file in the root directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of `consult/1` does not need to be an absolute path.  It is just relative to the working directory of Prolog that you may get using `?- pwd.`

That still requires you to save the file.  That too is not necessary if you can transfer the data through some other means (e.g., networking).  If you can somehow get a Prolog stream to the data you can use `load_files/2` using the `stream(In)` option to load the program file.

Comment: thanks for the response. I would prefer the stream option. Can i use a bytearraystream to load files? And if yes, what is the command to the prolog?`load_files(mybytearrayInputStream, stream(in)) `??

Comment: AFAIK there is no link between Prolog streams and Java streams.  So, you need to get the content into a Java string, get that into Prolog (preferably as a Prolog string) and call `open_string(String, Stream)` to get a Prolog stream.  Then you do `load_files('mongodb:some-id', [stream(Stream)])` to load the data.  `mondodb:some-id` is just a name.  Any name will do.  Using the same replaces the content rather than adding.  Do not forget to close the stream.

Comment: i tried this. But again error occurs. In my pl file i have a compile command that uses some other files. The `'C:/mypath'` of the complie returns an error. I tried to escape it with `\` character before `'` and now the error is about 
` ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`
`ERROR: In:`
`ERROR:   [22] throw(error(instantiation_error,_4552))`
`ERROR:   [19] '$source_term'(stream(test,_4594,[]),.... ` What can I do?

Comment: Add enough details.  What is in the file you try to load from mondodb?  Where are the referenced files?  Details matter, so please include literal snippets from the code.

Comment: Finally I managed to load them via http_open and load_files. The trick was to do it in a single line because otherwise Prolog does not recongnize Stream. Thanks a lot. I will mark answer as accepted